# Каким образом указать, что 1 но любой из элементов simpleType должен заполниться данными?

Tags: xml, xsd

Готовлю схему xsd. В схеме есть `SimpleType`, любой 1..* из элементов которого l должны заполняться обязательно.

*Пример:* Может быть заполнен `температураВоздуха`, а остальные будут пустыми (данными не подаются по ним), ИЛИ может быть заполнена `ТемператураВПолости`, а другие будут пустыми, ИЛИ может быть заполнены все и т.д.

Вопрос: Каким образом указать, что один но любой из элементов `simpleType` должен заполниться данными?

```
<xs:simpleType name="Объект">
<xs:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="температураВПолости" type="xs:int"/>
```

Comment: Ровно один или хотя бы один?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov хотя бы один или несколько

Comment: _The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:element' element is not supported in this context._ - Внутри `simpleType` никак не может быть `element`.

Comment: Напишите, какая версия XmlSchema используется: 1.0 или 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из вариантов решения:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Объект">
<xs:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="температураВПолости" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Comment: Это вообще что? Это же невалидный кусок схемы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov почему не валидный?

Comment: Внутри simpleType никак не может быть element. Такова спецификация xml schema. Неужто ваш xml-редактор, которым вы пользуетесь, не указывает на ошибку? Неужто ваш xml-парсер, которым вы пользуетесь, принимает эту схему?

Comment: К тому же, если бы эта схема была валидной, то в ней не задано наличие минимум одного элемента. У всех `minOccurs="0"`, значит могут отсутствовать все. Если вам нужно лабораторку сдать, и похрен на ошибки, так и скажите, и не морочьте людям головы. А единственный работающий вариант я привёл в своём ответе.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 1. xml редактор не указывает на ошибку.  Эту схему отдам принимающей стороне. В аннотации укажу что может быть 1 или несколько элементов, если нет данных ни в одном из элементов, то данные (simpleType) не отправляется.  2. xml парсер не у меня, на другом программном обеспечении. 3. Подскажи пожалуйста, а на чем ты проверяешь валидность xsd?

Comment: Я использую IDE Visual Studio. В неё встроен редактор, полностью поддерживающий xml-спецификацию, она умеет создавать и проверять XmlSchema, умеет выполнять xslt-преобразования. Но платная - только ради xml покупать её явно не стоит. Есть бесплатная версия, но в ней несколько урезаны средства работы с xml (нет xslt).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо большое. Попробую программу и создание xml там. Сам использую Oxygen XML Editor

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать конструкцию [`<xsd:choice>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256109(v=vs.120).aspx), которая допускает появление ровно одного элемента из группы

```
<xsd:choice>
  <xsd:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xsd:int"/>
  <xsd:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xsd:int"/>
  <xsd:element name="температураВПолости" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

Если нужно наличие хотя бы одного, то можно попробовать так

```xml
<xsd:choice>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВПолости" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВПолости" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
    <xsd:element name="температураВПолости" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

Comment: допускаться должно один или несколько элементов из группы... Антон, подскажите пожалуйста, есть решение такого варианта? к сожалению, сам не смог осилить такое пока...

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Попробуйте

Comment: не получается. Отображается  ошибка, как я понял, жалуется, что не может быть несколько похожих элементов.

Comment: _Multiple definition of element 'http://ns/request:температураВоздуха' causes the content model to become ambiguous._

Answer (score 0):

Простого способа нет. Можно попробовать следующее:

```
<xs:element name="Объект">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="температураВоздуха" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="температураВПолости" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="температураВнутриКомнаты" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="температураВПолости" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="температураВПолости" type="xs:int"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Эта схема требует задание как минимум одного элемента. Можно указать несколько, но только в том порядке, в котором они перечислены.

К тому же, это никак не может быть `simpleType`, только `complexType`.